# How to call a void method of a C# class from javascript - ASP .Net MVC C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, call, void

I need your help for a problem I don't manage to solve :)

I have this form in my program to upload a file

```cs
@using(Html.BeginForm("UploadDocuments", "User", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "form-upload-documents" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <ul id="UploadContainer" class="upload-container" data-last-id="0">
        <li class="col-upload-figure">
            <figure class="upload-figure">
                <label class="btn-upload" for="Picture_0">
                    <span class="btn-upload-text">Add a picture</span>
                </label>
                <input class="custom-input-file" data-id="0" id="Picture_0" name="Picture_0" type="file">
            </figure>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="form-submit">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-loader" data-style="expand-right" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
}
```

And I check the size of the file I want to upload with javascript, if the file is too large, I would like to call a void method of a C# class without leaving the current page

```js
    $('#Picture_0').change(function() {
        var files = $(this).prop('files');
        var fullPath = $(this).val();
        if (files[0].size > 4*1024*1024) {
            $('#Picture_0').val('')*;

            // The function of a specific class I would like to call
        }
        else{
            //...
        }
    })
```

How can I perfom that ?

Comment: You would need to make a ajax call to a server method that executes the code (but its unclear why you want to do this - what does the _function of a specific class_ do?)

Comment: Hi @StephenMuecke, this function adds an error message in the list of a class which will display a temporary red banner with the error message for each error message in the list, I usually use it in my C# code for server side validation of runtime errors, but I would like to use it for client side validation too :)

Comment: Then refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50131612/how-to-call-a-c-sharp-method-of-a-specific-class-from-javascript-asp-net-mvc?noredirect=1#comment87281539_50131612) for a `ValidationAttribute` that gives you both client and server side validation (the link at the bottom of the question)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, you link this page in your comment ^^"

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand you comment (and that should have read _bottom of the answer_)

Comment: Oh my bad, I'm gonna check it...

Comment: Why you need void method ? That return nothing.

Comment: @AsifRaza I know, but the method I want to call in that specific case is a void method. I don't want a value in return, just to inform a class there are errors to display :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ajax call would solve this. Something like:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'@Url.Action("Action", "controller")',
    type: 'POST',
    data: //Your data,      //Possibly a json
    contentType: 'Application/json',
    success: function(result)
    {

    }
});
```

Comment: the problem is the method is not an Action, just a void method :/

Comment: What exactly is your function doing? If all it does is upload an image. You can change the function to an ActionResult and simply return a Json.

    'return Json(new {Success = true});' 

this simply returns a bool.

Comment: This void function adds an error message in the list of a c# class which will display a temporary red banner with the error message for each element in its list, one by one

Comment: I usually use it in my C# code for server side validation or runtime errors, but I would like to use it for client side validation too

Comment: @KilliCo You can still do this using ActionResult and returning a Json. Nothing should really change.

Comment: Okay, I'm gonna try it :)

Comment: @KilliCo  I would say that Adrian is right. The could I give you should not give that error. Try putting a break point at the beginning of you function and run through it.

Answer (score 0):

You can call this by ajax,

```
public ActionResult MethodName()
{
    // your logic
    EmptyResult e = new EmptyResult();
    return e;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Well if it is in a controller then it should have ActionResult as return type.

However if you want to call a function then you should use webapi.